# Как определить уровень высоких частот в изображении?

Tags: обработка-изображений

Как определить уровень высоких частот в изображении?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: А почему вы решили, что это учебное задание? Это не так.

Comment: пока оно таковым выглядит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сделать двумерное преобразование Фурье и найти мощность спектра высокочастотной части (с большими индексами)